# Sequences of functions $f_n(x) = \frac{x^n}{n}$ on $(-\infty,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $f_n(x) = \frac{x^n}{n}$ on $(-\infty,\infty)$. Find its Limit function $f$.

Now, $lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = \frac{x^n}{n}$ is $0$ for all x $\in [-1,1]$

when $x=2$, the sequence of functions becomes $\{2,\frac{2^2}{2},\frac{2^3}{3},...,\frac{2^n}{n}$}, when $n \to \infty$ , $f_{n}(2) \to \infty$.

So the sequence of functions $f_n(x)$ does not converge on $(-\infty,\infty)$.

Am i right? Please correct me where i was wrong..

Comment: You are correct in that in general your function $f_n$ does not converge. However the working shown is no way near enough.

Comment: Just a thought, might it be x to the n'th over n factorial? Because I think then it is an example of pointwise convergence without uniform convergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct, to the extent that the poorly phrased question can even be answered correctly.

There is, first of all, a problem with the question. When finding the limit of a sequence of functions, you need to first explain if you are interested in a point-wise limit or something else (like uniform convergence)

In your case, your proof actually (poorly) proves that a point-wise limit of the sequence does not exist. Since uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence, this also means that the sequence does not converge uniformly.

Why did I say poorly? Well, your proof is a little unclear. Because what you are proving is unclear, that is to be expected, but that is not a good excuse. Your language is very un-mathematical. You are using mathematical terms, but you are using them incorrecly. Strictly speaking, a mathematitian could ask you the following questions:

- Where is your proof that $$\lim_{n\to\infty f_n(x)} = 0?$$
- What do you mean "when applying limit"?
- What do you mean by "we get $\infty$"?
- You say "So the function does not converge on $(-\infty,\infty)$". Which function does not converge? What does it mean for a function to "converge"?

Comment: Ya...you are right ..Thanks for the Tip...May be Next Time I wont use these Languages...I am sorry..guys..

Comment: I have edited my question, pls tell me whether, it is right..